# How to save uploaded file using primeng fileupload?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to use primeng fileupload. But I'm not able to find out how to save the uploaded image on some given path. I get `uploadedFiles` object but I'm not able to save the file to a given path.

```
<p-fileUpload multiple="multiple"
                                  name="DefaultFileUploadFileInput[]"
                                  [url]="uploadUrl"
                                  accept="image/*"
                                  maxFileSize="1000000"
                                  (onUpload)="onUpload($event)">

                        <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                            <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                                <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
                            </ul>
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-fileUpload>
```

Angular Code:

```
uploadUrl: string;
uploadedFiles: any[] = [];

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private demoUiComponentsService: DemoUiComponentsServiceProxy
    ) {
        super(injector);
        this.uploadUrl = AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/DemoUiComponents/UploadFiles';
    }

    // upload completed event
    onUpload(event): void {
        for (let file of event.files) {
            this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
        }
    };
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Do you have PHP or some backend code at this url "AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/DemoUiComponents/UploadFiles'" that will accept the file and save it on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in name atrribute we define name that is used in the server site to identify the files .
use following code .. rename  name="DefaultFileUploadFileInput[]" to **name="DefaultFileUploadFileInput"**

```
<p-fileUpload                     multiple="multiple"
                                  name="DefaultFileUploadFileInput"
                                  [url]="uploadUrl"
                                  accept="image/*"
                                  maxFileSize="1000000"
                                  (onUpload)="onUpload($event)">

                        <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                            <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                                <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles"> 
                                 {{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
                            </ul>
                        </ng-template>
 </p-fileUpload>
```

in API add following code..

```
/*** File Upload
     * @throws JSONException ***/
        @RequestMapping(value = "/UploadFiles/", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes="multipart/form-data")
          public @ResponseBody String uploadFileOperation(
                  @RequestParam("DefaultFileUploadFileInput") MultipartFile[] files) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, JSONException {
         String filePath="xyz/Test FileUpload/";
         File saveDir = new File(filePath);
               if(!saveDir.exists())
               {
                   saveDir.mkdirs();
               }
 for (MultipartFile file : files) {
                        File f= new File(filePath,file.getOriginalFilename());
                        String Filename=file.getOriginalFilename()
 try {
                                file.transferTo(f); //Transfer or Saving in local memory 
                            }catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
//your logic here
}
            return "file upload done"
          }
```